# How can I allow a click to pass through a div but still react to hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have `divA` that partially overlaps `divB`. How can I allow clicks on `divA` to pass through to `divB` but still have `hover` fired when hovering over `divA`?

I'm aware of `pointer-events:none;` and this makes the clicks pass through but it also prevents the hover.

I have also tried the below, but it did not allow clicks to fall through

```
$(document).on('click', '.feedback-helper', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
})
```

Picture the relation of the divs like:

[image]

Here is the why of it (read as: *"let's avoid an X Y problem"*):

I'm working on an implementation of [feedback.js](https://github.com/ivoviz/feedback)

To see the issue:

- view the [feedback.js demo](http://ivoviz.github.io/feedback/)
- click the feedback button in the bottom right
- draw a box on the screen to highlight a section
- click the "black out" button
- try to draw a box *inside* the first box  **you can't because the click is blocked by the first box**

I need to allow drawing a blackout box over a highlighted area but if I set `pointer-events:none;` I will lose other hover functionality I have on those elements.

#### [Here is a jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/dzmqs55p/1/)

All solutions welcome

Comment: how did you listen to the event that creates the "black out" blocks? maybe we can change something there? (for instance, apply this event also to boxes elements). edit: also try reading this http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/

Comment: How about setting up a page level click event handler (window.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {...}) and in that function check the event.target to see what object actually initiated the event and react accordingly?

Comment: @Ness Ill have a look into the source for the plugin and see, it uses canvas which I know little about so I was hesitant to change anything in there

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm hoping there's a more straightforward solution but Ill keep that in mind

Comment: Why don't you just do this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/162/

Comment: @NenadVracar doesnt that work because a is *inside of b* there? That is not the case for me

Answer (score 1):

You could get the click event for the overlaying element to initiate the click event for the underlying element.

Native JS Example:

```js
document.getElementById('divA').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('Clicked A');
});
document.getElementById('divB').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  event.initEvent('click', true, false);
  document.getElementById('divA').dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer;  
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#divA {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: whitesmoke;
}
#divB {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}
#divB:hover {
  background: green;  
}
```

```html
<div id="divA"></div>
<div id="divB"></div>
```

jQuery Example:

```js
$('#divA').on('click', function() {
  alert('Clicked A');
});
$('#divB').on('click', function() {
  $('#divA').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer;  
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#divA {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: whitesmoke;
}
#divB {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}
#divB:hover {
  background: green;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divA"></div>
<div id="divB"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked your example page and if you set a slightly lower z-index on data-type="highlight" that could take care of the problem, try a z-index of 29990 in comparison to your current 30000. This should allow you to target the highlighted feedback area and overlay it with the blackout elements.

Comment: Wow, I totally thought this had something to do with the canvas aspect of the plugin an looked right over `z-index`

Comment: Actually, this doesnt quite solve it, the hover doesnt register correctly, see https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/dzmqs55p/3/, if you look at the original, when you hover over a highlighted box, an x pops up in the top right to delete the highlight. That no longer works if  we change the z order

Comment: Yeh I see what you mean, just had a look at the example page there. It's a tricky one ! I'm having a hack on your example page, i'll let you know if i figure anything out !

Comment: Ty, I'm deep into the plugin now myself, not going to be simple for sure

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a pseudo element instead. Perhaps that will do what you need.

```js
$('#toggleBlack').on('click', function() {
  $('#divA').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#divA {
  background: whitesmoke;
  position: relative;
}
#divA.hidden:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divA">Highlight the text once I'm hidden and cut/copy/drag</div>
<br />
<br />
<button id="toggleBlack">Toggle Hidden</button>
```