# Remove click function, but keep hover intact

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Since my last question was marked as a duplicate, while it was no duplicate, and no-one is changing it back, I will just ask my question again.**

I have an `<a>`, which has, by default, a on-click function. This `<a>` also has a hover, which I would like to keep.

How do I disable the click function, but keep the hover?

P.s., I would love to see a CSS solution!

**Important! Last time, my question was marked as a duplicate of this question: [How to disable a link using only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-link-using-css), but `pointer-events:none;` is also blocking the hover.**

If it is still a duplicate, please mark it as a duplicate of a question that is truly a duplicate.

---

Edit:
I forgot to mention, that my hover is made like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/7o3dbak7/7/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li id="item1"><a href="somelinkthatistherebecauseitis">hoverable object</a></li>
    <li id="item2">text object, here comes alot of text explaining certain features of the website.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container ul #item2 {
  display: none;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer
}

.container ul #item1 {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.container ul #item1:hover + #item2 {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I voted to close your previous question as I misunderstood what you were asking. In future, rather than asking a new question, simply edit your question to clarify your intent (and explain why you feel it isn't a duplicate).

Comment: So do you really need to use an anchor element there? Anyway James answer is still valid: https://jsfiddle.net/7o3dbak7/1/

Comment: So you want something like a tooltip, you can put the text of  #item2 id inside #item1 in a <div> tag and you can show it on hover of  #item1 id. Why are you creating multiple <li> tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a \`pointer-events:hoverOnly\` or similar in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168420/is-there-a-pointer-eventshoveronly-or-similar-in-css)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add `pointer-events: none` to the `a` element, then apply the hover to the parent element, targeting the `a` specifically within that:

```css
span a {
  pointer-events:none;
}

span:hover a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span><a href="#">Hello, world!</a></span>
```

Comment: Okay, that works, but my hover works a bit different. Let me add it to my question!

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen rather than applying `pointer-events: none` to your `#item1` element, apply it directly to the `a` element. `.container ul #item1 a { pointer-events: none; }`

Comment: Well, in my case, the a tag is not inside a li to be honest :p

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen I'm not really sure what you're asking. Your question states that you want to disable the click function but retain the hover on an `<a>` element. The markup you've given shows an `<a>` element within a `<li>` element. What are you actually wanting to happen?

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen your HTML here is invalid. `<a>` elements are not allowed to be direct children of `<ul>` elements.

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen simply do what I've done in my answer here; wrap the `<a>` element in a `<span>` element and apply the `pointer-events: none` specifically to the `<a>` element: https://jsfiddle.net/7o3dbak7/8.

Comment: Yes! That worked perfectly, stupid I didn't think of it. Thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would not use anchor to begin with. Replace anchor with a paragraph tag and modify your CSS.

CSS:

```
.container #item2 {
    display: none;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <p id="item1" href="somelinkthatistherebecauseitis">hoverable object</p>
    <div id="item2">text object, here comes alot of text explaining certain features of the website.</div>
</div>
```