# How to make clickable button?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an problem with pointers, in my project i  have an box of notification and i want to make not hover, i did it in this way with  pointer-events: none :

```
.ui-pnotify.ui-pnotify-fade-normal.ui-pnotify.ui-pnotify-move{
        top: 47px !important;
    right: 0px !important; 
    pointer-events: none !important;
```

}

but the problem is that i want to make an button in this box  not hover but just clickable, this class :

.ui-pnotify-action-button{

}

I just want to be clickable not hovered because i have a big problem with hover.
Can you help me please.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about styling? On Hover there should be no style and on click there should be some style. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you please tell us what this means in understandable english? "i have an box of notification and i want to make not hover"

Comment: @DhavalJardosh no, i just dont want to be hover(to manipulate with pointer-events maybe), but just clickable

Comment: what's is the current behavior and what is the expected behavior??

Comment: @DhavalJardosh when i do this class in this way .ui-pnotify-action-button {
pointer-events: auto;
}

works but hovering, I wonder if there is any way to disable the hover but clickable button

Comment: `pointer-events: none` disables all actions - click, drag and hover. So it's not possible using this property.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22170212/7427111

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168420/is-there-a-pointer-eventshoveronly-or-similar-in-css

Comment: Possible to show your code so we can mess around with it?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh thank you very much for answers, the function is very big, I am trying to make in any way just to not hover, anyhow is problem to show all the function, thank you

Comment: @MusicalEcho thanks for information.

Comment: By hover you mean the pointer shouldn't change to clickable hand icon?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh, no no, thanks bro because i find another solution thank you very much, i am so thankful to you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to apply your styles using pseudoclasses? It seems you don`t want to see some styles.

```
.ui-pnotify.ui-pnotify-fade-normal.ui-pnotify.ui-pnotify-move:hover{
    top: 47px !important;
    right: 0px !important;
    // whatever you want it not to be while it is been hovered
}
```

Also, consider to remove !important and a lot of classes - it`s not a good practice.