# Angular make button not clickable?

Tags: angular

I need to make a button disable but I have tried several things and they don't work and I need to make the button base on the condition not clickable.
like :

```
 [disabled]="existReview != false" // this make the button disable but still if i click the buttons takes me to the page normaly
 [disabled]="!existReview" // doesn't work
 ng-disabled="!existReview"// doesn't work .
```

my button looks like this :

```
 <app-primary-button *ngIf="!userIsPartner || !isLogged"
        routerLink="{{getAddReviewLink()}}" 
        ng-disabled="existReview != false"
        matTooltip="{{ (!existReview ? 'apps.mouse-over-enabled' : 'apps.mouse-over-disable') | translate}}">
        Write review
      </app-primary-button>
```

I give the boolean value in ts:

```
this.reviewService.verifyUserHaveReviewToApp(this.app.appIdToSearch)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.existReview = res;
      });
```

DO you have any idea what am I missing, thank you?

Comment: What boolean value have you declared in ts file on init

Comment: Please, provide class and template of your <app-primary-button/> component

Comment: Are you sure `res` is a boolean? Have you tried to log it? `console.log(res);`

Comment: @PrashanthDamam I add in the question the boolean value .

Comment: yes is a boolean

Comment: @Sal `this.existReview` is getting the value correcly, the problem is at disable binding or i don't know

Comment: If the res value is true then try using 
`[disabled]=existReview`

Comment: And it may be any error in your `<app-primary-button>` component

Comment: yes I used that and explain in the question it makes it button looks inactive but if I click it works normal and in this case I don't want the button direct me anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here isn't the `[disabled]`, your first use of it is fine. The problem is that `routerLink` doesn't care about the disabled attribute.

To get around this issue you can have two buttons:

```
<app-primary-button *ngIf="(!userIsPartner || !isLogged) && existReview"
    [disabled]="true"
    matTooltip="{{ (!existReview ? 'apps.mouse-over-enabled' : 'apps.mouse-over-disable') | translate}}">
    Write review
</app-primary-button>
<app-primary-button *ngIf="(!userIsPartner || !isLogged) && !existReview"
    routerLink="{{getAddReviewLink()}}"
    matTooltip="{{ (!existReview ? 'apps.mouse-over-enabled' : 'apps.mouse-over-disable') | translate}}">
    Write review
</app-primary-button>
```

Comment: I think your answer helped me a lot to solve the problem that's why I will accept your answer, and please if you don't mind to vote my question, just want to have the opportunity to ask more question in the future and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The button is disabled but the routerLink is still active.
You can try to add an additional css class in order to disable click events...something like this:

```
<app-primary-button
[ngClass]="{'disable-click': disabled}"
...
/>
```

In your css:

```
.disable-click {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: this makes the job done but I have a small problem I need that matTooltip to be shown @riorudo

Comment: You can try to change the css class like this:
`.disable-click:active {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}`. I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31355432/8712609)

Answer (score 1):

Your `<app-primary-button/>` is a custom component. So it doesn't know anything about some `disabled` property.
You should provide this property (you can name it whatever you want) and transfer it correctly to the inner button (I assume you have it inside), for example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-primary-button',
  template: `
     <button [disabled]="disabled">My real button</button>
  `
  })
export class PrimaryButton {
  /**
  * Provide an input for the property
  * and use it in the template
  */
  @Input() disabled = false; 
}
```

Then you'l be able to use your custom button as `<app-primary-button [disabled]="true"></app-primary-button>`

Comment: this component has it already otherwise I would have get and error that was not part of it, what I am saying is that makes the button look inactive but if I click it, it does the same thing, with this, I only change the color of the button

Comment: Please, provide the class and template of your PrimaryButton. StackBlitz example would be more than welcome